# How to force or bring vertical scroll bar to front in html css

Tags: html, css

I would like to bring this `vertical scroll bar` to the front. Here is the image.
I do not know how to set it.

[image]

## UPDATE

I did a work around but the wrong part is that the items text element are not hidding behind the header. Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/badcoder28/bpdkw3sw/)

```css
.container
{
  position: absolute;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
}

.table-header
{
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.table-body
{
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 25px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 30%;
}

.table
{
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-header">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <th>
          Header
        </th>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="table-body">
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Item 1
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Item 2
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Item 3
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Item 4
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Item 5
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Item 6
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Item 7
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please show snippet or jsfiddle of it  or your website link. Thanks

Comment: @Pranjal nope i would like to make it visible if the item list is overflowing

Comment: i think i did it here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/badcoder28/bpdkw3sw/ but the sad part is the items text element are not hidding behind the header

Comment: in your link its already on top

Comment: what browser are you using ?

Comment: @XzenTorXz i tested it both in chrome and moz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the scrollbar is on your table, there's no way you can have the scrollbar on top of the table header, and your table below the table header. Your best bet is to have it offset from top the height of the header:

So change your current CSS for your table body:

```
.table-body
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 30%;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpdkw3sw/3/).

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Instead of adding `padding-top:25px` you need to add `margin-top:25` to `.table-body`

---

This should work. Adding `z-index` to `.table-header` will fix the issue.

```css
.container
{
  position: absolute;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
}

.table-header
{
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:1000; 
  background: red;
}

.table-body
{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 25px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 30%;
}

.table
{
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-header">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <th>
          Header
        </th>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="table-body">
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Item 1
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Item 2
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Item 3
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Item 4
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Item 5
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Item 6
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Item 7
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is my main problem sir the scroll bar hides behind the header but i would like to bring it to from then scroll bar appear and hides it when items are not overflowing in the parent content

Comment: Updated my answer. Give it a try and let me know  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can bring `header` on front by using `z-index` and after that just adjust the width of header to scroll-bar.

```css
.container
{
  position: absolute;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
}

.table-header
{
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  width: 96.8%;
  background: red;
  z-index:1;
}

.table-body
{
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 25px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 30%;
}

.table
{
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-header">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <th>
          Header
        </th>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="table-body">
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Item 1
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Item 2
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Item 3
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Item 4
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Item 5
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Item 6
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Item 7
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is actually what i want but there is still a problem what if the items did not overflow inside the `table-body`? the scroll bar is hidden but the header width remain the same

Comment: sorry didn't understand

Comment: you want to show scrollbar always show even there is not items??

Comment: no sir, i would like to show the scroll bar if the item is overflow just like in any common table function, i hope i explained it well

Comment: ya. it's showing scroll-bar because there are so more items than the height of main parent

Comment: if you remove the items till 2nd item the scroll bar will hide

Comment: yea its hide but i pointing out that the **width remain the same**

Comment: @SagarKodte guess he is talking about `.table-header` width. Its currently **96.8%**. Making it **100%** should fix his issue.

Comment: so you want to make width of header 100% after scroll bar hide?

Comment: @Tympaaz yes that is what i want but if you go for **100%** when there is more items than the height of the main parent the scroll bar hide behind the header

Comment: @SagarKodte exactly sir

Comment: this is little confusing to do..wait let me edit..you also want to keep scrollbar on top..

Comment: yes it is since i am new to web dev, glad for helping me